# Ubuntu 15.10beta, automatic update

Tags: 15.10, beta

I have worked successful with Ubuntu 15.10 beta. Now the Ubuntu 15.10 is released will I get an automatic update via software centre?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** *This has been answered before, for each previous Ubuntu release.*

---

There is NO difference, once the release date has arrived AND your system is fully updated.

*If you were already up-to-date, you won't even need an 'automatic update'.*